# Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: statistics

[image]

$Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent random variables, each with probability function
$$
P(y)=\binom{y-1}2 p^3(1-p)^{y-3},\quad (y=3,4,5,\ldots).
$$
Find the MLE of $p$.

I tried rearranging the result in fourth line many times but I still couldn't get the answer in the fifth line. Can someone please tell me how to derive the fifth line in the solution?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: A problem with scanned images that may not have occurred to you is that they cannot be searched. Neither google nor the local search function can find keywords from these. As the main objective of the site is to provide a database of useful bits, this is a problem. It will cause the regulars to disprove of your posts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry about that. The main problem is that I do not know how to input mathematics equations and notations. I am new to this site and I tried generating mathematics equations in "Help" page but I did not managed to use it comfortably.

Comment: Tommy, by clicking the edit-button under your question you can see how I did it. There are a couple of pitfalls, but you'll get the hang of it soon enough. You can ask for help. Many others are eager to show you how LaTeX works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assign $A = 3n$, and $B = \sum y_i - 3n$.  Then $$\frac{A}{\hat p} - \frac{B}{1-\hat p} = 0,$$ or equivalently, $$\frac{A}{\hat p} = \frac{B}{1-\hat p},$$ or $$\frac{\hat p}{A} = \frac{1-\hat p}{B}.$$  Now cross multiply and collect like terms in $\hat p$:  $$B \hat p = A (1- \hat p),$$ or $$(A + B) \hat p = A,$$ or $$\hat p = \frac{A}{A+B} = \frac{3n}{\sum y_i},$$ as claimed.  One of the most useful tools in algebraic manipulation is to recognize the basic, underlying structure of an equation that needs to be solved, and to simplify or distill the expression (using auxiliary variables can help as in this case) while preserving that structure.  Eliminate unnecessary complexity and cumbersome notation, and reduce the problem into its most basic elements.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

And here is the solution of this question.